# The agent job of the release pipeline is missing UI part 'artifact download'

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

According the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops-2020) there should be an atrifact download Component

This is de UI in devops2019 and devops2020.

[image: UI devops 2019 and devops 2020]

In devops services it looks like this

[image: devops services]

[image: Probaly the documentation isn't correct]

Comment: Seems like the documentation might be wrong.  What version of Server 2019 are you on?  The features timeline seems to indicate that it would be included, but I see it missing.  Regardless, it will still download the artifacts, you can't just optionally select which ones.

Comment: I use devops 2019 release 1.1 and devops 2020 (released 6okt 2020).

Answer (score 1):

This feature may not be deployed to the azure devops server. The azure devops server is usually upgraded once a long time, and the auzre devops service is upgraded [once a month](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-176-update), so some features are available in the azure devops service, but not in the server. Regarding the upgrade of the azure devops server, you can follow the [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2020?view=azure-devops-2020).
Before that, you may need to wait patiently for the release of this feature.

Comparison of release notes of azure devops server and service:

[image]  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Hugh

As a workaround, we can enable the option **Skip download of artifacts** and add task `Download build artifacts` and select the artifact you want to download.

[image]

Result:

[image]